# How can I properly position an HTML element under other content on the page?

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem figuring out how I can position a background section behind other content. Check the image below to see what I am talking about. But basically what I am trying to achieve is moving the beige section(outlined in red) up to the dark gray section so they are touching.
[View image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYXY0.png)

I have tried using various CSS properties and nesting HTML elements in various ways but I could not find a solution. Here is some code as it sits currently. Also, I am using Wordpress for anyone curious and I doubt this matters in this instance.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 135rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
  background-color: var(--darkGray);
  height: 35rem;
}

.banner-sub {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.banner-img {
  width: 768;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.banner-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.banner-text {
  justify-content: left;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="banner-content">

        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . " /img/img1.png "; ?>" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="banner-text section">
          <h2 class="">Removed</h2>
          <p class="">This is a paragraph in the banner. Text goes here.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="banner-sub" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . " /img/beige-section.png "; ?>" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>
```

As you can see I removed some text and removed parts of the first image. I do not intend to advertise the start up company I am working for, only here to learn. We have our site all done just trying to recreate parts of the site someone else has done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you need to include the relevant code in your question to reproduce the problem, so that we can see what might be causing it and be able to help.

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase - "they are touching"? Need a smooth transition? Or what do you mean?

Comment: ...and you have provided a little code, which means that it will be difficult for us to help.

Comment: I want the beige section directly below the dark gray section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a linear gradient in your css with four stops. Making the two in the middle both stop at 50%.

```css
    .banner-content {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        /* Adding the background color */
        background: rgb(53,51,45); 
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(53,51,45,1) 0%, 
                                            rgba(53,51,45,1) 50%, 
                                            rgba(231,224,190,1) 50%, 
                                            rgba(231,224,190,1) 100%);

    }
    .banner-img {
        width: 768;
        height: auto;
        /* display: flex; */
    }
```

```html
<div class="banner-content">        
            <img class="banner-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/EW1RtiS.png" alt="" />
    <div>
```

Comment: Great. Happy to help!